# ffmpeg combine two command

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg

```
INPUT="input.mp4"
OUTPUT="result.mp4"
OPSI="'FontName=Arial Bold,FontSize=22,PrimaryColour=&H0009FAFD,OutlineColour=&H00000000'"
```

## Adding Subtitle

```
ffmpeg -i $INPUT -vf subtitles="f=$SUB:force_style=$OPSI" -y $OUTPUT
```

## Scaling Movie

```
ffmpeg -i $INPUT -vf scale=-1:720 -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -level:v 3.1 -c:a copy $OUTPUT
```

Both command worked when i execute it one by one, but i want combine **rezise** and **adding subtitle** into single line command,

```
ffmpeg version 3.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
```

Can you help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
INPUT="input.mp4"
OUTPUT="result.mp4"
OPSI="'FontName=Arial Bold,FontSize=22,PrimaryColour=&H0009FAFD,OutlineColour=&H00000000'"

ffmpeg -i $INPUT -vf "subtitles=f=$SUB:force_style=$OPSI,scale=-1:720" -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -level:v 3.1 $OUTPUT
```

Filters can be executed in sequence by invoking both, separated by a comma.

Comment: You should provide more details.